# Geoserver wfst ajax call

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t, ajax

I am writing a feature into postgis behind geoserver using wfst and using jquery ajax call. When the user is authenticated it successfully adds a feature. When user is not authenticated it still returns to the success function instead of error function. When i log the returned data using:
data.getElementsByTagName("ExceptionText")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
I get this exception message:

Error performing insert: Cannot access critical_areas with the current privileges

Which makes sense as the user is not authenticated, but instead of going to the error function why is it still returning this to the success function? Can you please suggest what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: There's no error in the ajax so error is not called

Comment: So how to handle this exception then?

Comment: Inform the user what happened?

Comment: Ok, that is clear now, i have a supplementary question, Is there any way to logout a user from geoserver? so that after logging out he is unable to make transactions?

Comment: you need to ask a new question